# Multiplicative Noise Term vs Additive Accumulative Noise Term

Tags: econometrics

This question arises from reading of [Sannikov and Scrzypacz (2007)](https://web.stanford.edu/~skrz/SannikovSkrzypaczAER07.pdf) and [Green and Porter(1984)](http://www.dklevine.com/archive/refs41147.pdf), which are modeling the same thing, dynamic collusion under imperfect monitoring, in a continuous-time version and a discrete-time version. Their choice of different noises term are crucial to derivation of their conclusions.

My question is how to decide which one is dominant for a particular market(e.g. European banana market) regarding the modeling of noises. My guess is that multiplicative noise term is more relevant to shocks of weather, additive accumulative noise term(following Brownian motion in Sannikov and Scrzypacz's case) is more relevant to shocks related to institution, say, cultural revolution and Khomeini's return to Iran.